# The given path's format is not supported - Using time data

Tags: c#

I trying to save some data to a text file inside a folder:

I have tried to change `dd-MM-yyyy-hhmm` To `dd-MM-yyyy-hh:mm`, and I tried to use the debugger to check where is the problem but I couldn't find anything.

**Code:**

```
public static string Folder(string mode)
{
    string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hhmm - ");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(str + mode);
    return str + mode;
}
```

The resulting behaviour should be similar to, the user saves the data, it will create a new folder with this name.

For example:

`(example - http - 26-5-2019-1514)`, inside the folder - `Results.txt`

Comment: Debug your code and see the value of `str+mode`. Maybe there is an illegal character in it.

Comment: Did you inspect the string? My guess would be that the format you're using is using colons for separating time, or slashes for the date, if you want to enforce using a minus sign you probably need to escape it with single quotes, like `"dd'-'MM'-'yyy...`, but I may be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: Also note that you probably want to use `HH` rather than `hh`.

Comment: This question is duplicated and full of Ambiguities.why did it get vote up?

Answer (score 0):

You should check input for invalid characters

for windows - `\/:*?"<>|`

for linux `/`

or maybe prefer other way and define allowed characters for your case 
my suggestion is `0-9a-zA-Z-._`

Example of cleanup process

```
  var invalidCharacters = new string[] {"\\", "/", ":", " *", "?", "<", ">", "|"};

  var temp = a.Split(invalidCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  a = String.Join("", temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have colons on the filename
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/filename

> Short and long file names must not contain the following characters:
>
> slash (/) or ()
>
> question mark (?)
>
> vertical bar (|)
>
> right angle bracket (>)
>
> left angle bracket (<)
>
> colon (:)
>
> asterisk (*)
>
> quotation mark (")
>
> In addition, short file names must not contain the following
>   characters:
>
> plus sign (+)
>
> comma (,)
>
> semicolon (;)
>
> equals sign (=)
>
> left square bracket ([)
>
> right square bracket (])